# Android Image blur as we scroll up

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to scroll up and blur the image above it.I want image to be static and blur only when we scrolling up.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: what do you want to scroll up ? list? activity? please provide details ....

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/kikoso/android-stackblur

```
_stackBlurManager = new StackBlurManager(getBitmapFromAsset(this, "android_platform_256.png"));
_stackBlurManager.process(progress*5);
_imageView.setImageBitmap(_stackBlurManager.returnBlurredImage() );
```

Then you have to find the position of the user. Every view can have a scrolling listener, just like that:

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

         int scrollX = rootScrollView.getScrollX(); //for horizontalScrollView
         int scrollY = rootScrollView.getScrollY(); //for verticalScrollView
         int progress = // DO SOME MATH HERE TO GET THE PROGRESS FOR THE BLUR
    }
});
```

Just mix the two things according to your situation.